# Is there a way for selecting extra fields - not to be saved - in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to execute the following sql in hibernate:

```
SELECT emp.*, utilsPkg.getEmployeeDisplayName(emp.id) FROM employee emp;
```

So far so good...
The thing is - I need it to be fetched to an entity - so I can update the employee.
Of course that the pl\sql function is not updateable nor part of the actual table...

How can I generate such an entity in hibernate - with a field that is calculated and not updateable?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `@Formula` annotation, as explained in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6481):

> Sometimes, you want the Database to do some computation for you rather
>   than in the JVM, you might also create some kind of virtual column.
>   You can use a SQL fragment (aka formula) instead of mapping a property
>   into a column. This kind of property is read only (its value is
>   calculated by your formula fragment).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@Transient` annotation on the getter method for that property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but you can always use [Hibernate entity lifecycle callbacks](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html#d0e3013) or you can provide it directly in your query:

```
select new MyEntity(o.column1, o.column2, utilsPkg.getEmployeeDisplayName(o.id)) from MyEntity as o where o.id = 5
```

Of course you must implement appropriate constructor.

Comment: This is not valid HQL. And it won't return an attached entity. See my answer to understand what the OP wants, and how to do it.

Comment: Hmm... I just copy-pasted this HQL query from production code and it works. Can you tell me what is not valid in it?

Comment: If it works, then it must be valid, and I stand corrected. I guess the utilsPkg.get...() function call is passed as is in the generated SQL. Didn't know you could call arbitrary SQL functions like this in HQL. But it still won't return an attached entity.